# Simplifying a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Given $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, \ \alpha\neq1 $  and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \ $ find the values of $ \ \theta \ $ such that

$$ \alpha \cos\left(\beta \theta \right)=\cos\left(\left(\beta+1\right) \theta \right)\,$$

in terms of $\alpha \ $ and $ \ \beta$.

Comment: You can use cos(A+B)=cos (A)cos (B)-sin(A)sin(B) to simplify the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: Do you mean that for all $\theta$ there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha\cos(\beta \theta)=\cos((\beta+1)\theta)$, or do you mean that there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that, for all $\theta$, $\alpha\cos(\beta\theta)=\cos((\beta+1)\theta)$ ?

Comment: @Gae. S. I don’t think OP meant “for all theta”, because that would be more or less trivial (alpha would need to equal to 1 so that the ranges of both sides of the equation are equal. But then only beta = -1/2 would work I think)

Comment: Given alpha and beta, both sides of the equation will repeat (have common periodicity) every lcm(beta,beta+1), which by the way, is always beta*(beta+1) = beta^2+beta

Comment: @Gae. S. just to be clear- I think what OP means is, “given alpha and beta, how do you find all solutions to the equation?”

Comment: Indeed, as @AdamRubinson said, I meant “given alpha and beta, how do you find all solutions to the equation?”

Comment: I think that this is a good question with no obvious simplifying tricks for alpha =/= 1, and I reckon for each pair alpha and beta, you would have to use some numerical root methods like Newton-Raphson. I haven’t spent awfully long thinking about this though so I may well be missing something

Comment: The solutions will repeat (i.e. you will get finitely many “different” solutions up to a period) if and only if beta is rational. Else, if beta is irrational, there are infinitely many different solutions, with no periodicity in them

Comment: Where did this question arise from?

Comment: I guess a more general version of this original question would be to find $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, \ \alpha\neq1, \ $   $\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \ \gamma\in\mathbb{R} \ $ such that $$ \alpha \cos\left(\beta \theta \right)=\cos\left(\gamma \theta \right),\,$$

although I suspect this can be reduced to:

$$ \alpha \cos ( \theta )=\cos\left(\gamma \theta \right),\, $$

without loss of generality.

Comment: I'm trying to analyze the convergence of some equation for my research (I'm a PhD student) and got this equation in the process. I'll try using numerical methods as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, not an answer, but I find it interesting to generalise this question - WLOG - to:

Given $a\in\mathbb{R}, \ b\in\mathbb{R}, \ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}, \ \alpha\neq1 , \ $   $\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \ $ and $ \ \gamma\in\mathbb{R} , \ $ find the values of $ \ \theta \ $ such that

$$ \sin \theta = a \ \sin\left(\alpha \theta +  \beta \right)\ + b \ ,$$

in terms of $\alpha \ $ and $ \ \beta$.

e.g. $ \sin x = 5 \sin (2x-6) + 3 \ $ looks like:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx+%3D+5sin%282x-6%29+%2B+3

although you don't need to use integers.

This basically is asking: "find all the intersections of *any* two sinusoidal waves".

But why stop there? You could also think even more generally and think, "what are the solutions to a line intersecting a sinusoidal wave, e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F20+%3D+sin%28x%2B1%29

Again, I suspect numerical methods are in order.
Or a quadratic and a sine wave? The possibilities are endless...

I'll probably post these as questions on SE at some point.